# Preview the contents of an application in Task Bar

Tags: taskbar, desktop-icons

How can I preview apps in task bar so that I can close certain windows of a running application without having to click and open the particular application and instead pointing would show the previews of the various windows? I am running Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can install compizconfig-settings-manager, then in the miscellaneous section you can toggle on window preview.